# Does the function $\frac1{1+|z|^2}$ have a power series at $z=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Does $\frac1{1+|z|^2}$ have a power series at $z=1$? If not, why not? How can we generally say that a function has a power series?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "in $a=1$"? Do you want a power series in some disc centred at $z=1$?

Comment: A function has a power series expansion about a point if and only if it is analytic at that point.

Comment: I mean that we expansion in a=1. So a is the a in: sum(a_n*(z-a)^n))

Comment: Can I say 1/(1+|z|^2)=1/(1+x^2+y^2). Than we calculate u_x, u_y, v_x and v_y. u_x=-2x and u_y=-2y, and of course v_x=v_y=0. So this function is only analytic in z=0.

Comment: @RoosJansen : please clarify your _question_ and don't just explain it in a comment.

Comment: @RoosJansen : functions of a complex variable involving the norm, real part, imaginary part, or conjugate in an essential way are rarely analytic.

Comment: Yes, but I have to prove that.

Comment: @RoosJansen : you suggest an obvious way yourself in a comment : the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  If you grind them out, I'll bet both of them are valid almost nowhere in the complex plane.  The answer gives a much easier way, but you should explain exactly why this works in your homework.  And please clarify your question, for the sake of all future readers.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, after working out the Cauchy Riemann-equations we see that this function is analytic only in z=0. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

At $z=1$, the gradient of the function in the real direction is $-1/2$ but the gradient in the imaginary direction is zero. So this function cannot be expressed as a power series in $(z-1)$.